# How checksum works in Paytm Gateway

Tags: checksum, gateway, paytm

I am new to this payment gateway and was trying to implement Paytm Gateway.

What I have understood about checksum is that it is used to find out if the request is tempered or not and to implement it, we are creating the checksum before sending the request to the paytm gateway and checking the same in response that we are getting from the paytm gateway.

I have gone through the sample Paytm gateway code mentioned in the below Github URL and couldn't understand how it is validating the checksum in  the paytm response. Its calling the verifyCheckSum method on line 73 after that its just checking if the transaction is successful or not irrespective of the verifyCheckSum returned value.

https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_NodeJs/blob/master/checksum/server.js

Am I missing anything??

Answer (score 1):

Paytm has upgraded the checksum library. The github link for the latest library is mentioned on the developer page of paytm. Also mentioning the link of github here as well:
https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_Node_Checksum